# Problem with image column in XtraTreeList

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtratreelist

I use XtraTreeList control.

There are 2 columns: first for text and second for icon

Problem : I can't change default icon (zero index in corresponding imagelist). There are 3 images in imagelist.

For example I need to show icon which is located at 2 index

Code

```
 TreeListColumn col = treeList1.Columns.Add();
            col.Caption = "Text";
            col.Visible = true;

            TreeListColumn colImage = treeList1.Columns.Add();
            colImage.Caption = "ImageColumn";
            colImage.Visible = true;


            RepositoryItemImageEdit imageEdit = new RepositoryItemImageEdit();
            imageEdit.Images = imageList;

            treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(imageEdit);
            colImage.ColumnEdit = imageEdit;

            treeList1.BeginUnboundLoad();

            TreeListNode node = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "trololo", 2}, null);

            node.SetValue(colImage.AbsoluteIndex, 2);

            treeList1.EndUnboundLoad();
```

Comment: you want to have different icons beside nodes (like solution explorer in visua studio)? or images in another column?

Comment: images in another column, thats why I have to use XtraTreeList instead of standard TreeView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody

Using RepositoryItemPictureEdit solved my problem. A little bit complex, but works

```
 TreeListColumn col = treeList1.Columns.Add();
            col.Caption = "Text";
            col.Visible = true;

            TreeListColumn colImage = treeList1.Columns.Add();
            colImage.Caption = "ImageColumn";
            colImage.Visible = true;

            RepositoryItemPictureEdit imageEdit = new RepositoryItemPictureEdit();
            imageEdit.ShowMenu = false;

            treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(imageEdit);
            colImage.ColumnEdit = imageEdit;

            treeList1.BeginUnboundLoad();

            Image img = imageList.Images[1];
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img);

            TreeListNode node = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "trololo", bmp }, null);


            treeList1.EndUnboundLoad();
```

Answer (score 0):

This task should be implemented using slightly different approach.  First, you should use the RepositoryItemImageComboBox and populate its Items property.  Each item has value and ImageIndex.  The TreeList will show in a cell image from the item whose value equals the cell value.  Here is the code which should work for you:

```
        TreeListColumn col = treeList1.Columns.Add();
        col.Caption = "Text";
        col.Visible = true;

        TreeListColumn colImage = treeList1.Columns.Add();
        colImage.Caption = "ImageColumn";
        colImage.Visible = true;


        RepositoryItemImageComboBox imageEdit = new RepositoryItemImageComboBox();
        imageEdit.SmallImages = imageList;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            imageEdit.Items.Add(new ImageComboBoxItem(i, i)); // i.e. value and image index

        treeList1.RepositoryItems.Add(imageEdit);
        colImage.ColumnEdit = imageEdit;

        treeList1.BeginUnboundLoad();

        TreeListNode node = treeList1.AppendNode(new object[] { "trololo", 2 }, null);

        node.SetValue(colImage.AbsoluteIndex, 2);

        treeList1.EndUnboundLoad();
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. But I need to show only image in the cell. I dont need combobox. Only simple image. Very simple task in my mind. That's why I use RepositoryItemImageEdit

Comment: I think this solution will work for you if the combobox button is hidden, unless you want to fill a cell with an image entirely.

Comment: @DevExpress Team, I think that this line `node.SetValue(colImage.AbsoluteIndex, 2);` can be removed, right?

Comment: @DevExpress Team, the combobox button will always appear? or is there a possibility to hide it?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of office.  It is possible to hide the button using the code, posted by @manji.